# ViewPager (cwac-pager) pages with non-unique tags not initialized properly

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I've encountered a problem with cwac-pager, and I can reproduce the problem in the PagerDemo demo project.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Run the PagerDemo project (it initializes 10 `EditorFragment` pages)
2. Delete pages 2-8 (nav to page 2 and press Delete until you're left on Editor #9)
3. You now have 3 fragments: Editor #1, Editor #9, and Editor #10. Swipe left to navigate back to Editor #1.
4. Press + to add pages. It starts by adding Editor #4 (evidently because there were 3 pages left after our deletes). Add pages until you've added up to Editor #10 (visible to the left of the current page).
5. Swipe right to Editor #9. The view does not load (there is no edit text for you to edit). Editor #10 (on the right) is the same. Swipe left to the *new* Editor #9 or Editor #10 to the left of Editor #1, and those views have loaded properly.

If you inspect `entries` in ArrayPagerAdapter at this time, you'll see that it has the correct number of `PageDescriptor`s, but some of the `PageDescriptor`s have the same tag, e.g. "editor9" and "editor10" appear twice. It seems like the fragments corresponding to these `PageDescriptor`s do not load.

The code in the demo project (and similarly in my project) for building the tags simply concatenates a string and the position of the fragment being created:

```
private String buildTag(int position) {
    return("editor" + String.valueOf(position));
}
```

As a workaround I modified `buildTag` to build a random tag:

```
private String buildTag(int position) {
    return("page" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
```

I'm not sure whether this workaround might have unintended negative consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this is a bug in the demo app, and `ArrayPagerAdapter` could use some defensive programming here to detect this case and raise an exception. I will work on fixing both. The `PageDescriptor` needs a unique tag, and my current demo app algorithm won't guarantee that, as you discovered. I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager/issues/2) for this.

Off the top of my head, a UUID should be OK, though I'll probably just use a monotonically-increasing integer counter.

Thanks for pointing this out!